# Random walks in Feller's 'An introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications'

Tags: probability, statistics, random-walk

In the book *'An introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications'* (3<sub>rd</sub> ed.) by **William Feller**, the 3<sub>rd</sub> chapter on random walks starts by considering a situation where we have

n = p + q symbols (x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>) standing for either +1 or -1.

Then the partial sum s<sub>k</sub>=x<sub>1</sub>+...+x<sub>k</sub> and s<sub>k</sub>-s<sub>k-1</sub>=x<sub>k</sub>=+/-1

After that, he writes the following (page 68):

"The arrangement (x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>) will be represented by a polygonal line whose *k*th side has slope x<sub>k</sub> and whose vertex has ordinate S<sub>k</sub>. Such lines will be called paths."

Up until this point, I have found this book to be extremely helpful and illuminating, but the first sentence really confused me.

If anyone could explain the terminology, the definitions or just illustrate the problem in some way, I would be grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it just means a diagram like [this](https://cdn.iopscience.com/images/books/978-0-7503-1251-6/live/bk978-0-7503-1251-6ch21f1_online.jpg) or [this](https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/411rand_files/image008.jpg), where the gradient of the $k$th line segment is $\pm 1$ according as $x_k$ is $\pm 1$